# PHP writing into text file while looping

Tags: php, mysql, excel, fwrite

I'm developing an app where user upload excel [.xlsx] file for dumping data into MySQL database. I have programmed in such a way that there is a LOG created for each import. So that user can see if there is any error occurred and etc.. My script was working perfectly before implementing the log system.

After implementing the log system i can see duplicate rows inserted into database. Also **die()** command is not working.

It just keep looping continuously!

I have written sample code below. Please tell whats wrong in my logging method.

**Note:** if i remove logging [Writing into file] script works correctly.

```
$file = fopen("20131105.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, "LOG CREATED".PHP_EOL);

        foreach($hdr as $k => $v) {
                $username = $v['un'];
                $address  = $v['adr'];
                $message  = $v['msg'];

                if($username == '') {
                    fwrite($file, 'Error: Missing User Name'.PHP_EOL);
                    continue;
                } else {
                     // insert into database
                 }
            }

        fwrite($file, PHP_EOL."LOG CLOSED");
        fclose($file);
        echo 1;
        die();
```

Comment: Just a thought, is it not possible to create  server logs in separate          folder ?

Comment: make sure $username = '' checks your condition correctly. Sometimes you have to user $username = '' || $username = ' '||is_null($username)

Comment: Can you post the values in $hdr ?

Comment: I just closed file within loop and its working good now fclose($file);

Answer (score 0):

First, your `die` statement is after your loop. It needs to be inside your loop to end it;

Second, you're looping over `$hdr`. It's not defined in your snippet tho. It has to be an array. What does it contain?

```
var_dump($hdr);
```

Comment: $hdr is an associative array. I'm sure there is no duplicates in $hdr array.
My script loops through $hdr array and checks if any data is missing. If there is any data missing
it will just log "Data is missing etc.." and skips instead of inserting it, command [continue]. die() command is written at end to ensure that script dies after completing the process

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for foreach as given in [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) highlights

---

"*Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset()."*[`[1]`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

---

Try unsetting the values in foreach using `unset($value)` . This might be the reason for duplicate values.